# Main thread hangs because of BlockingQueue's consumer (which I thought was on another thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I have a test that is blocking (first block of code). I have a few elements that are all working together. I have a blocking queue that I put events on to, then I have a consumer that takes them off and sends them to Amazon Kinesis. I am pretty sure that my test is getting blocked because the queue is blocking my consumer even though I thought it was running on a separate thread.

```
// Test.java
@Test
public void testWhileLoop() throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Event> testQ = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Event>(1024);
    // mockKinesis is a mock at the class level.
    KPLPoster kpl = new KPLPoster("TestStream", mockKinesis, testQ);
    Event event = new Event("TestMessage", "TestPartition");
    ListenableFuture<UserRecordResult> fakeReturn = Mockito.mock(ListenableFuture.class);

    final AtomicInteger numberOfWhileLoops = new AtomicInteger();

    Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        numberOfWhileLoops.incrementAndGet();
        return fakeReturn;
    })
    .when(mockKinesis)
    .addUserRecord("TestStream", "TestPartition", ByteBuffer.wrap("TestMessage".getBytes()));

    kpl.run(); // Hangs here

    for(int i = 100; i > 0; i--){
        testQ.put(event);
    }

    kpl.stop();
    kpl = null;

    assert(numberOfWhileLoops.toString()).equals("100");
}
```

Here is the run method of BaseKinesisPoster which my KPLPoster inherits. It should be noted that BaseKinesisPoster implements the Runnable interface.

```
//BaseKinesisPoster.java
@Override
public void run() {
    shutdown = false;
    while (!shutdown && !(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())) {
        try {
            this.runOnce();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is part of my KPLPoster's (which extends BaseKinesisPoster) relevant `runOnce()` method.

```
// KPLPoster.java
@Override
protected void runOnce() throws Exception {
    Event event = inputQueue.take();
    //other stuff in my method
}
```

How do I make sure that blocking on my queue consumer doesn't block my test/main thread?

Comment: I deleted my answer as I'd missed some key details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
Thread.run();
```

it invokes the method called. Nothing special happens and the method is run in the current thread.

When you call

```
Thread.start();
```

This starts the thread which in turn calls run() in that new thread.

BTW `Thread.stop()` will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` in Java 8.  You shouldn't use it. You should allow it to finish naturally.

Comment: I am not using `Thread.stop()` on the thread, its an implementation I have done myself. It basically turns `shutdown = true` so it jumps out of the while loop. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: I highly recommend not overriding standard methods, nor standard classes like Thread.

Comment: I am not overriding. The stop method is on the class within the thread, not on the thread itself. Its fine this way, right? If not why would that be bad? I totally understand not overriding Thread's stop method itself.

Comment: @bwighthunter you should override Thread at all as this leads to confusion. Just use it as a wrapper for Runnable.